# Release dates for Office 2010 in Canada

Tags: licensing, microsoft-office-2010

Are the Canadian Office 2010 release dates different from the American ones?

I'm interested in the volume license release date in Canada.  I beleive it was May 1 in USA.

Are academic open licenses different?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue has to be taken directly to the vendor, rather than sysadmin community...